# Charset Encoding in WildFly

Tags: jboss, character-encoding, wildfly, wildfly-10, undertow

All my application files were created using UTF-8 yet WildFly serves them as ISO-8859-1.

So I have a few questions:

- does WildFly have a default charset?
- how does WildFly choose the encoding used to set the charset response header?
- what is the difference between *default-encoding* and *url-charset* attributes in the WildFly Undertow subsystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default encoding of Wildfly using the following command on the CLI:

```
/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribute(name="default-encoding" value="utf-8")
```

`url-charset` is used for encoding/decoding the URL query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases request sent before specifying encoding so server encodes it with server's default encoding.

- default encoding of wildfly is ISO-8859-1, till wildfly25.
- the convention is: encoding is specified by request header, if not the server's default will be used. you can set it for wildfly 24+ by

`/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribute(name= default-encoding , value= utf-8)`

- answered